# List.clear() not emptying my List

Tags: apex, governorlimits, insert, dmlexception

The project that I am working on has an API endpoint that is meant to upload a large number of records into three different tables: `Careers`, `Degrees`, and `CareerDegreeRelationships`. The endpoint is suppose to upload all the careers, all the degrees, and then all of the career degree relationships.

For reference,

- There is 800+ careers and 500+ degrees, but there is 10,000+ CareerDegreeRelationships, so I know I needed to take a different approach in inserting those records.
- Each degree and career have a `externalId` reference that are used as a reference for creating the career degree relationships:
- A sample JSON might look like:

```
"careers": [
  {
    "externalId": 1,
    "name": "Career 1"
  },
  {
    "externalId": 2,
    "name": "Career 2"
  },
],
"degrees": [
  {
    "externalId": 101,
    "name": "Degree 1"
  },
  {
    "externalId": 102,
    "name": "Degree 2"
  },
],
"careerDegreeRelationships": [
  {
    "career": 1;
    "degree": 102;

  },
  {
    "career": 2,
    "degree": 101
  },
]
```

Here is basically what I did:

```
// Insert Careers and Degrees
List<Career__c> careers = new List<Career__c>();
for (Career career : requestBody.careers) {
    Career__c newCareer = new Career__c();
    newCareer.Name = career.name;
    newCareer.externalId__c = career.id;
    careers.add(newCareer);
} 
insert careers;

List<Degree__c> degrees = new List<Degree__c>();
for (Degree degree : requestBody.degrees) {
    Degree__c newDegree = new Degree__c();
    newDegree.Name = degree.name;
    newDegree.externalId__c = degree.id;
    degrees.add(newDegree);
} 
insert degrees;

// Create a map for both degrees and careers so that getting references for CareerDegreeRelationships is easy
Map<Integer, Career> careersMap = new Map<Id, Career>()
for (Career__c car : careers) {
    careersMap.put(car.externalId, car);
}
Map<Integer, Degree> degreesMap = new Map<Id, Degree>()
for (Degree__c deg : degrees) {
    degreesMap.put(deg.externalId, deg);
}


// Insert the Relationships
List<CareerDegreeRelationship__c> newRels = new List<CareerDegreeRelationship__c>()
for (Relationship rel : requestBody.careerDegreeRelationships) {
    CareerDegreeRelationship__c newRel = new CareerDegreeRelationship__c();
    newRel.Career__c = careersMap.get(rel.career).Id;
    newRel.Degree__c = degreesMap.get(rel.degree).Id;
    newRels.add(newRel);
    if (newRels.size() == 10000) {
        insert newRels;
        newRels.clear()
    }
}
insert newRels;   <<<<< ERROR
```

So as you will see, I basically create all the careers, create all the degrees, then I create maps for career and degree based with the externalId as the key to be used when creating the CareerDegreeRelationships.

Since I know there will be more than 10,000 relationships, you will see that if my newRels List ever gets to be 10,000 records, I go ahead and insert those 10,000, clear the list and then continue creating more.

Then in the last line of code I showed, you will see I insert the remaining items in the rels list (this is to insert the final x amount if less than 10000). However, I get the error that I attempted to insert 10,001 records on this line.... To me, this says that the `clear()` function is not working and my list is not actually being emptied.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to check if the clear() is working? why dont you use System.debug(newRels.size()) after you clear the list to see if its working.
You are also missing a semi-colon after newRels.clear()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 10,000 DML row limit is **per transaction**, not **per operation**. You can't update more than 10,000 rows from start to finish. If you need to do so, you'll need to use Batchable or Queueable methods to process more records.

Comment: And in this case, `Per Transaction` is the entire API method?

Comment: @BlondeSwan Yes, that's correct.